# Implementing a simple login app using the Node Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, http

I'm implementing a simple login app in the React and Node JS.
Here is the `express` server code:

```
const express = require('express')
const basicAuth = require('express-basic-auth');
const app = express()
const port = 3006


const auth = basicAuth({
    users: {
        admin: 'supersecret123',
        user: '456',
    },
    challenge: true, // <--- needed to actually show the login dialog!
})

app.options('/LOGIN/authenticate', function (req, res) {
    console.log("options CORS request...")
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'HEAD,OPTIONS,OPTIONS');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Authorization');
    res.set('access-control-expose-headers', 'Location');
    res.set('x-frame-options', 'SAMEORIGIN');
    res.send('options CORS request...')
})

app.use(auth)

app.get('/LOGIN/authenticate'/* , logOriginalUrl, logMethod *//* , auth */, (req, res) => {

    console.log("---> Login server: got authenticate request")

    const options = {
        challenge: true,
        httpOnly: true,
        signed: true,
    };

    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

    if (req.auth.user === 'admin') {
        console.log("---> Login server: admin")
    } else if (req.auth.user === 'user') {
        console.log("---> Login server: user")
    }

    res.send('authenticate ok...')

});

var server = app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log("=======================================")
    console.log(`=====> Login server listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

and the client:

```
import axios from 'axios';

export const authenticate = async () => {
    try {
        const res = await axios.get('http://localhost:3006/LOGIN/authenticate', { 
            auth: { 
                username: 'user', 
                password: '457' 
            } 
        });
        console.log("response OK");
        console.log(res.data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.log("\r\n===> authentication error: "+error);
    }
};
```

The doc says that when the option `challenge` is set to *true* like in my code above the browser should display a *popup* to enter credentials on unauthorized responses but it DOESN'T!. As I've investigated I'm getting the `WWW-Authenticate` challenge header on response BUT the browser DOESN'T display a popup!
What can be the reason

P.S.
I've tested it both on Firefox and Opera.

Answer (score 0):

if you hit this URL (http://localhost:3006/LOGIN/authenticate) directly on the browser then only it will ask to show a popup

Comment: Ok. Thx. Yes, it's true. So this popup mechanism  ONLY works when the user access the login page DIRECTLY by typing the address manually in the URL input!?

Comment: yes , api call we can pass in header or as per package requirement